# How do I get the filename of the executing jade script

Tags: pug

Is there a global object that is accessible from within a jade template with various parameters?

Is there a global variable with the path of the currently executing jade file?

```
!!! 5
html
  head
    title Test
  body
    //- I want to be able to know what the current script file is...
    p Hello, I am: #{globals.scriptfilename}
```

Answer (score 6):

If you're using `gulp-jade`, add `gulp-data` to the mix and use this code:

```js
var jade = require('gulp-jade');
var data = require('gulp-data');

gulp.src('**/*.jade')
    .pipe(data(function (file) {
        return {
            relativePath: file.history[0].replace(file.base, '')
        };
    }))
    .pipe(jade())
```

This will give you a `relativePath` in your `jade` templates that is something like `about/index.jade`, relative to the base folder.

I'm not entirely sure of where/how that `file.history` is generated, but in my case `[0]` pointed to the original filename (with its absolute path on the disk)

Comment: how do you access `relativePath` in the template?

Comment: It's going to be a global variable, so just type `relativePath` anywhere.

Comment: It works fine for me: [download demo project](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/141891/15/jade-global-variable-demo.zip). Refer to [`gulp-data`](https://github.com/colynb/gulp-data)'s docs if you have problems with it.

Answer (score 1):

My solution:

```
//gulpfile.js

var $path = require('path'),
    jade  = require('gulp-jade'),
    isProduction = process.env.ENV == 'production';

gulp.task('watch', function() {
    gulp.watch("**/*.jade")
        .on('change', function(event) {
            compileJade(event.path, isProduction);
        });
});

function compileJade(path, isCompress) {
    gulp.src(path)
        .pipe(jade({
            pretty: !isCompress,
            locals: {
                _path_: path,
                _basename_: $path.basename(path)
            }
        }));
}
```

In Jade file you can use _path_ and _basename_ like this:

```
<!-- #{_path_}, #{_basename_} -->
```

One more thing to notice: String interpolation does not work in jade comment. So following code will not interpolated in result html file:

```
// #{path}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a global variable. You can use Node's [util.inspect(object)](http://nodejs.org/api/util.html#util_util_inspect_object_options) to view it's contents.

It automatically replaces circular references with "[Circular]", unlike `JSON.stringify()`.

Using a boilerplate Express app, I found these:

- global.process.argv ==  `['node','/Users/mike/Development/test/web.js']`
- global.process.mainModule.filename == `'/Users/mike/Development/test/web.js'`

Comment: When suggesting edit make sure you are fixing everything in the post, don't pick and choose what to fix.  If adding new tags to a question, then make sure you also fix grammar, spelling, etc.