# gulp-data fields not rendering in jade template

Tags: javascript, node.js, pug

NOTE: I'm following this post:
[How do I get the filename of the executing jade script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12262844/how-do-i-get-the-filename-of-the-executing-jade-script)

Heres what I'm doing:

```
gulp.task('jade', function() {
    gulp.src("path/to/template")
    .pipe(data(function(file) {
        return {
            fileName: file.path
        }
    }))
    .pipe(jade())
    .pipe(gulp.dest("path/to/dest"));
});
```

My template looks like this:

```
.container
  p fileName
```

But when it renders, the `fileName` variable comes out as `undefined`. What am I doing wrong?

**NOTE**: If I log `file.path`, the value is *not* `undefined`.

Comment: Seems to be working fine for me, provided that you use `p #{fileName}` or `p= fileName` in your template.

Comment: Can you paste the snippet of code youre using? I still cant get it to work.

Comment: [Here's a gist](https://gist.github.com/robertklep/89761f64840ac858e4fd).

Comment: What version of gulp data are you using?